# Adblock preventing button from being clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, postback, adblock

I'm not able to click on my LinkButton in FireFox when I have either of the following extensions enabled:

- AdBlock Plus
- Disconnect

Any idea why this could be happening and what I could do to get around it? I've tried `CausesValidation ="false"` to no avail. It seems like the `javascript:__doPostBack()` function is just never called when these extensions are enabled.

Comment: Your linkbutton has most likely attached id/class/property/whatever like "share", "advertisement" or something similar. Adblock started to block even some facebook plugins for me, so it's kinda pain in the ass right now.

Comment: @walther thanks for the comment! Do you know if there's a list of such words I could compare against? I only have "performance", "tickets", "reserve", "content", etc.

Comment: ctrl+shift+F and there you can see all the filters that get applied. There's a search function as well.

Comment: @walther It ended up being an event handler attached to the linkbutton that was firing some Google Analytics code ... I'll likely post an answer of my own with a fuller explanation later, but if you can post your comments above as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fuller answer](http://bugsnpieces.blogspot.com/2014/11/postback-not-happening-on-asplinkbutton.html), but I had a click event binding to my LinkButton looked like this:

```
$(anchorEl).click(function () { 
                    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', anchorEl.href, {
                        'hitCallback':
                          function () {
                              document.location = anchorEl.href;
                          }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

Because of this the Javascript on the LinkButton was getting completely ignored and the `__doPostBack()` was not firing.